# Web scraping xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to learn how to extract some data from web pages. I use the following code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://www.otomoto.pl/oferta/mercedes-benz-klasa-s-s500-long-4matik-amg-ID6yEJqd.html#003d4d5f4e'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

data1 = tree.xpath('//div[@class="offer-params__value"]/text()')
headers= tree.xpath('//span[@class="offer-params__label"]/text()')
data2 = tree.xpath('//a[@class="offer-params__link"]/text()')
```

Part of web page with details about car (under the picture), there are many segments `li` with car info:

```
<li class="offer-params__item">
    <span class="offer-params__label">Rok produkcji</span>
    <div class="offer-params__value">                1985         </div>
</li>
```

https://www.otomoto.pl/oferta/mercedes-benz-w201-190-190-d-ID6yLUAR.html#xtor=SEC-8

Is there any way to extract only one value (in this case year 1985) that is strictly associated with label for it "Rok produkcji" and both are inside only one `<li>`? With my code I extract list of all car details and I see no direct correlation that for example take every second item or similiar, to be sure I always get this exact thing (in this case it is manufacturing date). Would be no problem if this list length would always be the same, but it changes. And data lists are separate, depeding if they are text or link.

Btw, if you could have some advices concerning web scraping, I would be glad to hear them. I am trying to learn Python and I am basically in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure `lxml` and Xpath solution :

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://www.otomoto.pl/oferta/mercedes-benz-w201-190-2-0-d-automat-oryginalny-przebieg-dealer-ID6yEHUr.html#f5942353bf'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

data = tree.xpath("//span[text() = 'Rok produkcji']/following-sibling::div/text()")[0].strip()

print(data)
```

Comment: Ettore, Do you know any materials that have it quite clearly explained?

Comment: If you want something a little more didactic than the official documentation, you can try books like * Web scraping with Python* by [Ryan Micthell](https://www.amazon.com/Web-Scraping-Python-Collecting-Modern/dp/1491910291)  or [Richard Lawson](https://www.amazon.com/Scraping-Python-Community-Experience-Distilled-ebook/dp/B00YSIL1XK/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1488121256&sr=1-3&keywords=Web+Scraping+with+Python). For Xpath or CSS Selectors syntax, you can give a look at the [W3C tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to do it using [BeautifulSoup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or `bs4`:

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.otomoto.pl/oferta/mercedes-benz-w201-190-190-d-ID6yLUAR.html'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

# search by tag and text/content and find the next sibling
found = soup.find('span', text='Rok produkcji').find_next_sibling('div')

# get the div's content
print(found.contents[0].strip())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This gave me some idea how it should be done. However, this exact chunk of code gives an error. `To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))`. Adding this solves an issue: `res = requests.get(url)
data=res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")`. Well, I need to figure out how to make a new line...

Comment: @Sebastian This is not an error, just a warning: BeautifulSoup warns that the parser is not mentioned and this could cause problems if the code is used on another machine. Just write `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")`and everything will be fine.

Comment: I see. I don't get any warning. Maybe because I'm using different python version